# How can I create an accelerate button to speed up my character?

Tags: phaser-framework

I've tried everything and it honestly seems like codecedemy is just horrible at teaching and the phaser docu is one I am not well familiar with.

```
const gameState = {}

function create() {
  gameState.codey = this.add.sprite(150, 200, 'codey')
  // Set cursor keys here!
  gameState.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys()

  gameState.keyA = this.input.keyboard.on("keyboard-A", function(){});
}

function update() {
    // Update based on keypress here!
   if(gameState.cursors.right.isDown) {
       gameState.codey.x += 5;
   }
   else if(gameState.cursors.right.isDown && gameState.keyA.isDown) {
       gameState.codey.x += 10;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `else if` logic will never run.

In order for the else if to run both `gameState.cursors.right.isDown && gameState.keyA.isDown` has to be true. However, the if starts with a check to see if `gameState.cursors.right.isDown`.

You have a few options, but I might do something like the following:

```js
if (gameState.cursors.right.isDown) {
    gameState.codey.x += gameState.keyA.isDown ? 10 : 5;
}
```

(Which is about the same as the following.)

```js
if (gameState.cursors.right.isDown) {
    if (gameState.keyA.isDown) {
        gameState.codey.x += 10;
    } else {
        gameState.codey.x += 5;
    }
}
```

You could also swap the order of your if/else if as well.

Another possible issue is that you're using `keyboard-A`, but I believe that should be `keydown-A`, based upon [Phaser.Input.Keyboard. KeyboardPlugin](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyboardPlugin.html).